# Evento onkeypress no detecta tecla retroceso

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un input text en el que escribo lo que pretendo buscar, uso el evento onkeypress para llamar a la función que toma el valor del campo y busca coincidencias. EL problema es que al borrar, al usar la tecla retroceso, no actua el evento onkeypress y no se llama a la funcion.

```
<input type = "text"  onkeypress= "entidades();" onchange= "entidades();"   class= "left-align form-control input-sm"    id="idProveedorPT" size="38" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `onkeydown` en vez de `onkeypress`. Se habla de esto en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire) pregunta en el SO.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con el método [onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp). Se ejecuta JavaScript cuando el usuario presiona una tecla.

```js
function entidades(){
    alert("Hello world");
  }
```

```html
<input type = "text"  onkeydown = "entidades();" onchange= "entidades();"   class= "left-align form-control input-sm" id="idProveedorPT" size="38" >
```